# Unset iTerm as the https:// handler

Tags: macos, iterm, url

I made iTerm the default handler for a number of protocols that it doesn't know how to handle. How can I unset these protocols? And how can I set them to be handled by Chrome?

So far I have tried removing the value from these protocols in this file:

> open ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist

But this hasn't worked. iTerm is still handling these protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install [RCDefault](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) and change all URLs associated to iTerm2 to their proper apps, especially https.

[image]

To unset iTerm2 handling particular URLs open the Apps tab, navigate to iTerm2 and untick those URLs.